# How to format&calculate the data using awk?

Tags: awk

1. I have the original data array as below:

```
1 2 1.07 
1 1 0.51 
1 2 0.54
```

2. I want to calculate the value of a and b with below calculation format, then regenerate the array as below

```
1 2 1.07 
1 1 0.51 
1 2 0.54 
a b
```

```
a=1*1.07+1*0.51+1*0.54==2.12 
b=2*1.07+1*0.51+2*0.54==3.73
```

regenerate the array as below format:

```
1        2     1.07 
1        1     0.51 
1        2     0.54 
2.12     3.73
```

Don't find the solution to merge the results, is there any suggestions, thank you.

```
$ cat data.test 
1 2 1.07 
1 1 0.51 
1 2 0.54

$ cat data.test|awk '{sum+=($1*$NF)}END{print sum}' 2.12

$ cat data.test|awk '{sum+=($2*$NF)}END{print sum}' 3.73
```

Comment: something like `awk -v OFS="\t" '{a=$1+$NF ; b=$2+$NF;print $0} END{print a "\t" b}' file` Good luck.

Comment: It works as expected now, thank you.

$ awk -v OFS="\t" '{a+=($1*$NF) ; b+=($2*$NF);print $0} END{print a "\t" b}' data.test
1 2 1.07 
1 1 0.51 
1 2 0.54
2.12    3.73

Comment: Hmm, based on your sample calculation `b=21.07+10.51+20.54==3.73` I think you wan t `a=($1*10)+$NF; b=($2*10)+$NF`, but if you're happy with your output I'm glad I could help. Good luck

Comment: There is some typo from my side, thank you for sharing.

a=1*1.07+1*0.51+1*0.54==2.12 
b=2*1.07+1*0.51+2*0.54==3.73

Comment: `$ awk -v OFS="\t" '{a+=$1*$NF; b+=$2*$NF} 1 END{print a, b}`

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs `1` should be something like `$1=$1;` otherwise OFS change will not be applied